# Retrofit OnResponse Get json error

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, retrofit, retrofit2

Im trying to connect my app with a web service using retrofit. I want to show a list using recyclerview.
The log shows this message: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established  but then got an error inside OnResponse and then the app falls

This is the main activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView rvMain;
    private RVMainAdapter mRVMainAdapter;

    private ArrayList<Chef> data;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        rvMain = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv_prueba);
        rvMain.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this));
        data= new ArrayList<>();
        mRVMainAdapter = new RVMainAdapter(data);
        rvMain.setAdapter(mRVMainAdapter);

        EndPointsInterface apiService = Conexion.getClient().create(EndPointsInterface.class);

        Call<ChefResponse> call = apiService.GetChefsCercanos(5);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<ChefResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ChefResponse> call, Response<ChefResponse> response) {
                int statusCode = response.code();

                    data.clear();
                    ChefResponse jsonResponse = response.body();
                     //NEXT LINE IS THE ERROR
                     data = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(jsonResponse.getresults()));
                     mRVMainAdapter= new RVMainAdapter(data);
                     rvMain.setAdapter(mRVMainAdapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ChefResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d("Error",t.getMessage());

            }
        });

    }
}
```

this is the interface

```
public interface EndPointsInterface {

    @GET("Chef/{idUser}")
    Call<ChefResponse> GetChefsCercanos(@Path("idUser") Integer id_usuario);
}
```

this is the jsonResponse class

```
public class ChefResponse
        implements Parcelable
{

    private Chef[] results;

    public Chef[] getresults(){
        return results;
    }
    public ChefResponse(){}
    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }
    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeArray(this.results);
    }
    public ChefResponse(Parcel in) {
        this.results = in.createTypedArray(Chef.CREATOR);
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<ChefResponse> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<ChefResponse>() {
        @Override
        public ChefResponse createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            return new ChefResponse(source);
        }
        @Override
        public ChefResponse[] newArray(int size) {
            return new ChefResponse[size];
        }
    };
}
```

and this is the adapter

```
public class RVMainAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RVMainAdapter.RVMainAdapterViewHolder> {

    private List<Chef> mLstChef = new ArrayList<>();

    public void add(Chef chef){
        mLstChef.add(chef);
        notifyItemInserted(mLstChef.size()-1);
    }

    @Override
    public RVMainAdapter.RVMainAdapterViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.chef_item,parent,false);
        RVMainAdapterViewHolder rvMainAdapterViewHolder = new RVMainAdapterViewHolder(view);
        return rvMainAdapterViewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RVMainAdapter.RVMainAdapterViewHolder holder, int position) {

        Chef chefs = mLstChef.get(position);
        holder.nombreschefscerca.setText(chefs.getTipoServicio());
        holder.ratingchef.setText(chefs.getRating().toString());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {return mLstChef.size();
    }

    static class RVMainAdapterViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView nombreschefscerca;
        TextView ratingchef;
        public RVMainAdapterViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            nombreschefscerca = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_nombreChefCercano);
            ratingchef = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_rating);
        }
    }

    public RVMainAdapter(ArrayList<Chef> chefs){
        this.mLstChef=chefs;
    }

}
```

the json Im trying to load is like this

```
<string xmlns="http://smartchef.org/">
[{"nombre_chef":"Cesar","rating":"3.5"},{"nombre_chef":"Bruno","rating":"3.8"},{"nombre_chef":"Gean","rating":"2.5"}]
</string>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your json top item isn't object with field **results** that is array of chefs. It is this array itself.
So you can modify json to something like this

```
{
     "results":[{"nombre_chef":"Cesar","rating":"3.5"},{"nombre_chef":"Bruno","rating":"3.8"},{"nombre_chef":"Gean","rating":"2.5"}]
}
```

or modify response in Endpoint definition

```
@GET("Chef/{idUser}")
Call<List<Chef>> GetChefsCercanos(@Path("idUser") Integer id_usuario);
```

Comment: if I change Call<List<Chef>> I also have the edit the adapter..I dont get your answer..can you be more specific please